# How can I detect the distance that the user's mouse has moved?

Tags: javascript, jquery, math

I'm trying to detect the distance the mouse has moved, in pixels. I am currently using:

```
$(document).mousemove(function(event) {
    var startingTop = 10,
        startingLeft = 22,
        math = Math.abs(((startingTop - event.clientY) + (startingLeft - event.clientX)) + 14) + 'px';
    $('span').text('From your starting point(22x10) you moved:   ' + math);
});
```

However, I  don't feel like this is the right way to do this, or is it? It doesn't feel to consistent to me.

Here is a demo of how it is working right now: http://jsfiddle.net/Em4Xu/1/

#### Extra Details:

I'm actually developing a drag & drop plugin and I want to create a feature called `distance`, like draggable has it, where you have to pull your mouse a certain amount of pixels before it drags. I'm not 100% sure how to do this, so first I need to get the pixels that the mouse has moved from the startingTop and startingLeft position.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Do you need to accumulate the distance or not?

Comment: Not sure what you're really trying to do, but distance between two points is calculated as: `Math.sqrt((deltaX * deltaX) + (deltaY * deltaY))`

Comment: Could you put this as an answer with some more details. I dont see how that would work.

Comment: No, I can't put it in an answer because I'm unable to understand from your question what you're trying to do.  Please clarify.

Comment: I'm actually developing a drag and drop plugin. And I want to create a feature called `distance`. Like draggable has it. Where you have to pull your mouse a certain amount of PX before it drags. I'm not fully sure how to do this. So first I need to get the PX that the mouse has moved from the `startingTop` and `startingLeft` position.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You got your math wrong. Here's improved version: http://jsfiddle.net/stulentsev/Em4Xu/26/

```
$(document).mousemove(function(event) {
    var startingTop = 10,
        startingLeft = 22,
        math = Math.round(Math.sqrt(Math.pow(startingTop - event.clientY, 2) + 
                                    Math.pow(startingLeft - event.clientX, 2))) + 'px';
    $('span').text('From your starting point(22x10) you moved:   ' + math);
});
```

Comment: But it doesnt work when using different numbers. Like here: http://jsfiddle.net/Em4Xu/30/

Comment: @Shawn31313: what do you mean "it doesn't work"? Seems working to me.

Comment: Never Mind. It was just when I put it into my plugin. I need to change something in the math. Thanks again for the answer.

Answer (score 13):

Here's a version that meters distance that mouse travels:

```js
var totalDistance = 0;
var lastSeenAt = {x: null, y: null};

$(document).mousemove(function(event) {
    if(lastSeenAt.x) {
        totalDistance += Math.sqrt(Math.pow(lastSeenAt.y - event.clientY, 2) + Math.pow(lastSeenAt.x - event.clientX, 2));
        
    $('span').text('So far your mouse ran this many pixels:   ' + Math.round(totalDistance));
    
    }
    lastSeenAt.x = event.clientX;
    lastSeenAt.y = event.clientY;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span></span>
```

Comment: This is not really what I want. Here is a better description of what I want: I'm actually developing a drag and drop plugin. And I want to create a feature called distance. Like draggable has it. Where you have to pull your mouse a certain amount of PX before it drags. I'm not fully sure how to do this. So first I need to get the PX that the mouse has moved from the startingTop and startingLeft position.

Comment: That tends to beg the question why you're reinventing the wheel rather than modding jQuery UI's draggable to accomplish your goal.

Answer (score 7):

Came up with the something similiar to Sergio, but this will calculate disatance from the point the mouse has been held down, and like jfriend said the distance between two points,

d = ( (x1-x2)^2 + (y1-y2)^2 )^(1/2)

```js
var totalMovement = 0;
var lastX = -1;
var lastY = -1;
var startX = -1;
var startY = -1;

$(document).mousemove(function(event) {

    if (startX == -1) {
        return;
    }
    if (startY == -1) {
        return;   
    }

    totalMovement += Math.sqrt(Math.pow(lastY - event.clientY, 2) + Math.pow(lastX - event.clientX, 2));

    $('span').text('From your starting point (' + startX + 'x' + startY + ') you moved:   ' + totalMovement);

    lastX = event.clientX;
    lastY = event.clientY;

});


$(document).mousedown(function(event) {

 startX = event.clientX;
 startY = event.clientY;
 lastX = event.clientX;
 lastY = event.clientY;

});


$(document).mouseup(function(event) {

 startX = -1;
 startY = -1;
 totalMovement = 0;
 lastX = 0;
 lastY = 0;

});
```

Comment: Thats just the amount the mouse has move. I need to detect how many PX away the mouse is from the starting point

Comment: Check the edit I made, it takes the total movement since the mouse has been held down now.

Comment: @Motes: you should put it into jsfiddle. It's much easier to test there :-)