# How to calculate mouse move distance from specify offset

Tags: javascript, jquery, mouseevent, offset, mousemove

I have some problem. I need to calculate some mouse move in pixels from `mousedown` event to `mouseup`. So i have this code:

```
selectArea.on({
    mousedown : function(e) {
        select = true;
    },
    mousemove : function(e) {
        var x2, y2, offset = $(this).offset();
            x2 = e.pageX - offset.left,
            y2 = e.pageY - offset.top,
            width = ?,
            height = ?
        ...
    },
    mouseup : function() {
        select = false;
    }
});
```

Now i need to know how many pixels i have moved mouse from mousedown offset to mouseup offset, is there any posible to calculate this? Much thx for help.

Comment: Is it not more simple to save mouse position in the `mousedown` and compare it with the actual location in `mouseup` ? So you can get rid of the `mousemove` and just do `mouseup mouse position - mousedown origin position`. Then you got your offset.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8686619/how-can-i-detect-the-distance-that-the-users-mouse-has-moved

Comment: Do you want to count the total number of pixels travelled, or just the distance covered from start position to the current?

Comment: The problem is that i need to draw some div with this coordinates, and hide it after mouseup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two different solutions, depending on your definition of "how many pixels i have moved"

**Scenario:** Mouse moves 25px to the right and 75px to the left.

**Solution 1: 50px; (distance between start and end)**

In the mousedown handler you save the coordinates of the mouse. In the mouseup handler you compute the difference between the current mouse coordinates and the saved ones.

**Solution 2: 100px; (distance traveled)**

In the mousedown handler you set a boolean to indicate you are recording and save the coordinates of the mouse and initialize the distance with 0. In the mousemove handler you compute the difference between the current mouse coordinates and the saved coordinates (add it to distance) and then you overwrite the saved coordinates with your current mouse coordinates. In the mouseup handler you output the distance and unset the boolean.

You code seems to be for the second solution, but the question asks for the first.

Comment: can u set some example?

Comment: Here's an example I just cobbled together to get the distance travelled: http://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/8ahQB/ although it sounds like you need the former.

Comment: Thx @Rory it's pretty much what i had in mind. I think it would be best to save the coordinates in the mousedown handler as well, because you miss the first tick of the mousemove in the current form. Also to make it obvious you unset them in the mouseup you could set to null or undefined. Final nitpick: if you move the mouse diagonally it registers as moving on the catheti.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan i've used your script, and everything is fine but i have one question, how to set up mouse reverse - when the mouse is moving back the values still growing, is there any option to replace it?

Comment: @Lukas you need to remove the `Math.abs()` function.

Comment: nice it's works prefect, i have one other small problem, this is works only for right side is there any option to set this for both sides?

Comment: I have no idea what you mean. Distance is defined to always be positive. If you want the relative offset moved on each axis, you should simply change your calculations in the mousemove or mousedown to update the offsets accordingly.

Comment: OK, i'v solved this problem, thx for help and your time. You can public your script and i will give u some up vote, if you want.